# Why does Filezilla only SOMETIMES prompt to overwrite files when transferring when transferring files of the same name?

Tags: file-transfer, overwrite, filezilla

I have noticed that only SOMETIMES when transferring a file of the same name that FileZilla prompts you to answer "do you want to overwrite?".

This might be weird, but this distracts my flow when expecting to have to overwrite but then doesn't ask me.  May you provide an explanation for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the settings of FileZilla to change its behaviour.

see http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/filezilla/filezilla_functions.htm chapter "Settings".

Use the Settings menu entry and the "Transfers" section. There you can define if every sent file will be automatically replaced or not with many more options.